# SDL2.DLL missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sdl

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.web.archive.org/web/20140330012735/https://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/15/lesson-0-visual-studio/) to setup the SDL template but when I try and run the program I get the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOHbC.png) error.

I have gone over the tutorial several times but cannot see what mistake I am making.

I copied the SDL2.DLL into the Release Directory and then ran it and I got a [different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmh7L.jpg) error.

but I imagine that I shouldn't have to do this?

Anyone see what mistake I could be making?

I am using windows 8 + MS Visual Studio 2012

Comment: The link to your tutorial is broken, fyi.

Comment: @GraemeRock: Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

There are two different versions of SDL2.DLL, one is x86 and another is x64. A common mistake is to use the x64 one when in fact you are compiling your code as x86. Try both of them to make sure you aren't making that mistake.

Comment: FWIW, this was the correct answer, at least in my case.  I had to download the [SDL2 windows development libraries](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php), then copy `\SDL2\lib\x64\SDL2.dll` to `C:\Windows\System32` and `\SDL2\lib\x86\SDL2.dll` to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.  Voila.